# How to fill a MUI Autocomplete TextField with Axios response?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I made a form so you can register you pet and on the text field (pet type) theres a  MUI Autocomplete component.
My question is... Is it possible to, when editing this pet, the MUI Autocomplete component already contains the information from the data base?
I tried this and it's not working.

```
//auto complete information... is working fine
const [tipos, setTipos] = useState<ITipo[]>([])

useEffect(() => {
        axios.get<ITipo[]>(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/tipo`)
            .then(resposta => setTipos(resposta.data))

    }, [])

//this part is not working, tring to fill the TextField when editing
const [tipo, setTipo] = useState<any | null>('')

useEffect(() => {
        if (parametros.id) {
            axios.get<IAnimal>(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pet/${parametros.id}/`)
                .then(resposta => setTipo(resposta.data.tipo.nome))

    }, [parametros])

<Autocomplete
                onChange={(event, value) => setTipo(value)}
                disablePortal
                id="tiposAutoComplete"
                options={tiposAutoComplete}
                sx={{ width: 300, marginTop: 1 }}
                renderInput={(params) => 
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    value={tipo}
                    id="especieField"
                    label="Tipos"
                    variant="standard"
                    required />}
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The MUI Autocomplete component is a react component that contains an input, so all I had to do was to access the input inside of it, it's explained on the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) under the topic "Controlled states".

This is how the code looks now:

```
<Autocomplete
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.valueOf === value.valueOf}
            value={tipo}
            onChange={(event, value) => setTipo(value as string)}
            inputValue={tipo}
            onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                setTipo(newInputValue);
            }}
            disablePortal
            id="tiposAutoComplete"
            options={tiposAutoComplete}
            sx={{ width: 280, marginTop: 1 }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField
                {...params}
                id="especieField"
                label="Tipos"
                variant="standard"
            />}
        />
```